# Passing two-dimensional array to a function in julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I have a three dimensional array defined as:

```
x=zeros(Float64,2,2,2)
```

I want to assign ones to `x` by passing `x` to a function, one layer at a time.
The function is:

```
function init(p,y)
   y=ones(p,p)
end
```

and I will pass `x` as follows:

```
for k=1:2
   init(2,x[2,2,k])
end
```

but when I do that, `x` is zeros, not ones. Why?

```
julia> x
2x2x2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

[:, :, 2] =
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
```

Any idea how to get Julia to assign ones to `x`?

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to use `slice`, which makes a `SubArray`:

```julia
x = zeros(2, 2, 2)  # Float64 by default

function init!(y)
    y[:] = ones(y)  # change contents not binding
end

for k in 1:2
    init!(slice(x, :, :, k))  # use slice to get SubArray 
end
```

Note that you can use `ones(y)` to get a vector of ones of the same size as `y`.

A `SubArray` gives a *view* of an array, instead of a copy. In future versions of Julia, indexing an array may give this by default, but currently you must do it explicitly.

For a discussion about values vs. bindings, see

http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2014/09/06/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory/

EDIT: I hadn't seen @tholy's answer, which contains the same idea.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also not sure I understand the question, but `slice(x, :, :, k)` will take a 2d slice of `x`.

If you're initializing `x` as an array of `Float64` and then hoping to assign a matrix to each element (which is what it appears you're trying to do), that won't work---the type of `x` won't allow it. You could make `x` an array of `Any`, and then that would be permitted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain I understand, but if you're trying to modify x in place, you'll want to do things a little differently.

The code below should do what you need.

```julia
x = zeros(Float64, 2, 2, 2)

function init!(p, y, k) 
    y[:, :, k] = ones(Float64, p, p) 
end


for k = 1:2
   init!(2, x, k)
end
```

And you might also want to keep in mind that the standard convention in Julia is to include an exclamation mark in the name of a function that modifies its arguments. And if I've understood your question, then you want your `init!()` function to do exactly that.

Comment: I think the question is about just passing one layer at a time, not the whole 3d matrix. If you do just that, pass one layer, then, apparently, a deep copy of that layer gets passed, and that gets modified in the `init` function, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed in Julia, and I thought I would update this answer to reflect Julia 1.5 (probably most of the changes were 1.0).  While I would expect the modern `x[:, :, k]` to work, as this is still refered to as a `SubArray` this actually is copy now when in an expression.  Instead you must use `view()`:

```
x= zeros(2, 2, 2)

function init!(y)
    y[:]= ones(size(y))
end

init!(view(x, :, :, 1))   # get reference to original items
```

This gives you the desired result:

```
julia> x
2×2×2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

[:, :, 2] =
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
```

There are also helper macros for writing it in a more palatable form,

```
init!(@view x[:,:,1])
```

but you run the danger of greedy macro parsing if you have other arguments, such that

```
otherfunc!(@view x[:,:,1], 10)
```

would give you an error `Invalid use of @view macro: argument must be a reference expression`.  To get around this, there is the kludge `@views` which turns all *SubArray*s into views, or you can wrap the argument in parenthesis.

```
otherfunc!(@views x[:,:,1], 10)
otherfunc!(@view( x[:,:,1]), 10)
```

You can find more information on the manipulation of Arrays and Matrices in this presentation:
[(Youtube) Arrays: slices and views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTGJ80HayK0)